# Why can't I find ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Tags: ubuntu-restricted-extras

I am trying to find ubuntu-restricted-extras in USC for 16.04 but no luck. Has it been re-named? Can the individual items still be found on USC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` or use `Synaptic` instead.  The package is there.

Comment: Synaptic worked but I can't "see" it in "search my computer" The same goes for VirtualBox5.02 and the extension package.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the multiverse repo enabled?  It shows up there on my xenial system.

Here's the output of `apt-cache policy ubuntu-restricted-extras`:

```
ubuntu-restricted-extras:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 65
  Version table:
     65 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
```

Comment: Got it with synaptic. That output shows for me too now. However, I don't see it visually with "search your computer"